# run-time controls eventhandler windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling

I am drawing a row of labels at run-time and attaching the name property to identify them
How do i get the eventhandler to get the selected/clicked run-time control property(text)

```
   for (int yy = 1; y < 40; y++)
   {
     Label TT = new Label();
     TT.Name = "TT" + yy.ToString();
     TT.Location = new Point(xx, zz);
     TT.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
     TT.Click+= new EventHandler(TT_Click);
     TT.Width = 20;
     TT.Text = yy.ToString();
      this.Controls.Add(TT);
       xx += 20;
    }

   void TT_Click(object sender,EventArgs e)
        {
               ???????????????
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

`sender` should be the thing:

```
void TT_Click(object sender,EventArgs e) {
  var label = (Label)sender;
}
```

Then do as you will with it, identify it and so on.

Beware, though, of these handlers being called improperly: too many times I've seen programmers invoke these 'manually' in code such as `TT_Click(null, new EventArgs())` etc. You'd do well to do some sanity checking as part of the logic.

Comment: cool, this worked and i getting some more stuff, i was looking only for the text property, i am also getting the gettype . how do i isolate these return types or choose only the text property? thanks once again

Comment: Sorry , got that one was using tostring() , shouldh have double checked to use the text property                                        void TT_Click(object sender,EventArgs e)
            {
                var labl = ((Label)sender);
                MessageBox.Show(labl.Text);
                //MessageBox.Show(label.GetType().GetProperty("Name").ToString());
            }

Answer (score 0):

```
 void TT_Click(object sender,EventArgs e) {
     if(sender == null) return; //return if the sender object is null
     MessageBox.Show(((Label)sender).Text); //Shows a MessageBox whith the Text of the Label
 }
```

Sender is an object which contains the sender of this event, in your case one of the labels. Now you have to cast it into a label and you can access the text-property.